# Scheduling system in PHP: Items disappear with button press

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a big issue with a classroom scheduling page. It filters the results by date, period and localization. With a specific place selected, after you press the shedule button, one of the bootstrap cards just disappear, It should show five rooms, but after any scheduling, it shows 4, and it keeps going down by one for each selected class.
Does anyone knows that could be causing that?When using print_r or vardump on the array, it shows the data of the card, but the card itself is not formed.The sql is fine, the data pass by and reach the array.
There is the page in the image below:https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG4r6.jpg 
Full code: https://onecompiler.com/php/3ybtzk66b
https://onecompiler.com/php/3ybtzv9bg
Thanks in advance.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$('#data_agendamento').mask('00/00/0000');

        $('#data_agendamento').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            language: "pt-BR",
            orientation: 'auto',
            startDate: "<?= $data_inicial_calendario ?>",
            endDate: "<?= $data_final_calendario ?>",
            daysOfWeekDisabled: "0",
            autoclose: true
        }).on('changeDate', atualizarTabelaAgendamentos);

        

    });
    
    function atualizarTabelaAgendamentos(cod_local) {
        $("#div_tabela_agendamento").html('');
        $("#div_tabela_agendamento").load("index.php?modulo=agendamentos&acao=tabela_agendamento",
                                                $("#frmAgendamento").serializeArray(),
                                                function() { 
                                                    if(! isNaN(cod_local)) {
                                                        document.getElementById(cod_local).scrollIntoView();
                                                    }
                                                });
    }
    function atualizarTabelaAgendamentos(cod_local)
    {
        $("#div_tabela_agendamento").html('')
        $("#div_tabela_agendamento").load("index.php?modulo=agendamentos&acao=tabela_agendamento")
    }

    
</script>
```

Script that reloads the page with button press

```
$aula[$i]['situacao'] = "<span class='text-success'>DISPONÍVEL</span>";
                    $aula[$i]['acao'] = '<button type="button" 
                                                onclick="gravar_agendamento('
                                                    .$imprimir['cod_el'].','
                                                    .$i.','
                                                    .$imprimir['cod_local'].
                                                ');atualizarTabelaAgendamentos('.$imprimir['cod_local'].')";
                                            
                                            class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm ml-md-4 botoes_agendamento">Agendar</button>';
```

Schedule class button

Comment: you are not supposed to link to code externally as these links often die at some point in the future. put the code directly in your post.